# bundle.js ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) after building with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have tried to start my project on server but when I open the page is white and in console it show that can't find budnle.js.

My folder structure is like this:

```
-dist
-node_modules
-public
-src
  -client
  -server
```

My `webpack.config.js` is in root folder and looks like this

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const outputDirectory = 'dist';
var SRC = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/assets');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['@babel/react',],
                        plugins: ['@babel/proposal-class-properties']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    require.resolve('style-loader'),
                    {
                        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
                    },
                    {
                        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                        options: {
                            // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                            // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                            ident: 'postcss',
                            plugins: () => [
                                require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                                autoprefixer({
                                    browsers: [
                                        '>1%',
                                        'last 4 versions',
                                        'Firefox ESR',
                                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                                    ],
                                    flexbox: 'no-2009',
                                }),
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            // Apply rule for images
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        // Using file-loader for these files
                        loader: 'file-loader',

                        // In options we can set different things like format
                        // and directory to save
                        options: {
                            outputPath: 'fonts'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            // Apply rule for audio
            {
                test: /\.(ogg|mp3|wav|mpe?g)$/i,
                include: SRC,
                use: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                // Apply rule for fonts files
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        // Using file-loader too
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: 'fonts'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                // Apply rule for video
                test: /\.(mov|mp4)$/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api': 'http://localhost:5000'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin([outputDirectory]),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
            favicon: './public/assets/img/favicon.png'
        })
    ]
```

};

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please see in the index.html the path for the bundle.js and see if it matches with the path hierarchy of bundle.js the dist folder. Also, let me know if you are able to download the bundle.js separately from the path

Comment: @Sunil I have this line in the bottom `<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>`

Comment: And where is bundle.js located in your dist folder? Please update the folder structure for dist folder so that hierarchy for bundle.js can be seen. It is possible that index.html is looking for bundle.js directly under dist folder but your code might be creating bundle.js somewhere else

Comment: @Sunil yes with index.html and favicon.png